# C usage of malloc on struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

I'm trying to use malloc on a struct called image. The function is:

```
void image_init(struct image* img, int w, int h) {
    img = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
    (*img).w = w;
    (*img).h = h;
}
```

And the function to free the image again is:

```
void image_destroy(struct image* img) {
    free(img);
}
```

But whenever I try to free the malloc-ed data I'm getting the error that the adress I'm trying to free was not malloc-ed before.

The struct of image is:

```
struct image {
    int w,h;
    int* data;
}
```

I call the functions with:

```
struct image img;
image_init(&img,100,100);
image_destroy(&img);
```

Comment: Did you check for what `malloc()` returns?

Comment: Let's save keystrokes with one-letter struct member names and then waste two characters on `(*img).w` instead of `img->w`! Brilliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First here

```
void image_init(struct image* img, int w, int h) {
    img = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
    (*img).w = w;
    (*img).h = h;
}
```

`img` is a *copy* of the original pointer passed to it, hence the code on first line inside function has no effect, since it makes the *copy* point somewhere - not the original object.

This:

```
struct image img;
image_init(&img,100,100);
image_destroy(&img);
```

doesn't make sense either (assuming you expected `img` to point somewhere after call to `init`). `img` isn't a pointer, how you expect it to point somewhere?

---

One way you could solve this could be

```
struct image *img = image_init(100,100);
```

where

```
struct image* image_init(int w, int h) {
    img = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
    (*img).data = NULL;
    (*img).w = w;
    (*img).h = h;
    return img;
}
```

Don't forget to call `free` on the pointer returned by above function - you will need to free `data` pointer separately too, in case you allocate it too.

---

**NOTE**: My best guess (if you also can't change prototype) is you want something like this:

```
void image_init(struct image* img, int w, int h) {
    img->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * w * h);
    img->w = w;
    img->h = h;
}
```

destroy:

```
void image_destroy(struct image* img) {
    free(img->data);
    free(img);
}
```

In main

```
struct image* img = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
image_init(img, 100, 100);
image_destroy(img);
```

PS. Or if you want the usage of those functions remain as you had in main go with the answer of Johnny Mopp.

Comment: Thanks. But the calls of image_init and the prototype of it were given to us to implement so I thought we can't change it. Are there solutions that don't change it?

Comment: Or alternatively you can keep the structure similar to the original, but pass `struct image **img` as a parameter and assign `*img` with the `malloc`ed pointer.

Comment: @user3745172 In this case you don't need `malloc`. The function should be provided with an already allocated structure pointer. As you do in the question. Just remove the `malloc` line and you are done.

Comment: @user3745172 In that case you might need to use pointer to pointer. Refer to google please, check how to initialize a struct using pointer to pointer.

Comment: @user3745172 see update, if you can't change prototype

Comment: @Giorgi No need for `malloc` in main. It can be statically allocated as in the question...

Comment: @EugeneSh. No in that case he won't be able to use destroy function

Comment: Maybe `image_init` is supposed to `malloc` the `data` pointer.

Comment: Well, yeah. The interface lacks consistency.

Comment: Don't forget that it is a good idea to ensure that all elements of the structure are properly initialized.  If you don't set the `data` element to NULL, you won't know whether the memory has been allocated for it or not — in general.  Your revised version does this by assigning to `data`, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I made a change if I correctly understood your suggestion, initially I missed there was data pointer inside the structure in the first place :)

Answer (score 3):

I think your assignment is not to allocate the `img` but the `data` ptr:

```
void image_init(struct image* img, int w, int h) {
    img->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * w * h);// Check for failure...
    img->w = w;
    img->h = h;
}
void image_destroy(struct image* img) {
    free(img->data);
}
```

Comment: This makes a perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct image img;
image_init(&img,100,100);
image_destroy(&img);
```

allocates an image struct on your stack. Why are you trying to malloc one? If you really want one on the heap then do

```
    struct image * image_init( int w, int h) {
        struct image *img = malloc(sizeof(struct image));
        img->w = w;
        img->h = h;
        return img;
    }
...  
    struct image *img = image_init(100,100);
```

Note the more idiomatic '->' use

if you want the one on the stack then do

```
void image_init(struct image* img, int w, int h) {
    img->w = w;
    img->h = h;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to cast the malloc to struct because the return value of malloc is of type void.

Comment: Beware of applying rules enforced by C++ compilers to C code.  They're different languages, and this is one place where there's a crucial difference.